# ASP.NET MVC LinQ - Use our own method in "Any" LinQ expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, authentication

I'm coding a login page in asp.net mvc thanks to multiple articles found on the web but I have a problem to find the matching user in the database.
Here is my POST method :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "username, password")] user model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = model.username.ToLower();
            string plainPassword = model.password;

            bool userValid = db.user.Any(u => SHA512.VerifyHash(plainPassword, u.salt, u.password) && u.username_canonical == username);

            if (userValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I got a "NotSupportedException" in this line :

```
bool userValid = db.user.Any(u => SHA512.VerifyHash(plainPassword, u.salt, u.password) && u.username_canonical == username);
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean VerifyHash(System.String, System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is what in my mind :
VerifyHash returns true if the provided password (uncrypted) matches with the crypted one stored in database (by getting the salt corresponding to the username, in database and re-encrypting the provided password with this salt, then compare the newly encrypted hash with the stored one).
Usernames are uniques.

I understand that it doesn't accept my VerifyHash method inside the "Any" one. But I don't know how to do else because I need the corresponding salt and encrypted password (u.salt and u.password) in addition to the matching username to verify the password.

I tried to use the "Find" method in the same way but it doesn't work (VS Error, by memory I need the user ID to pass it as a parameter). I'm new with LinQ to Entities.

Any idea ? Forgive my eventual english mistakes.

Thanks,

Hellcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an exception, because entity framework cannot translate method `VerifyHash` to SQL syntax. `VerifyHash` is implemented in C# and it does not have a corresponding method in SQL.

Why don't you first search user by username and then verify the password. You can do it like this:

```
var userFromDB = db.user.FirstOrDefault(u => u.username_canonical == username);
if(userFromDB !=null)
{
    var userValid = SHA512.VerifyHash(plainPassword, userFromDB.salt, userFromDB.password)
    if (userValid)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) 
It seems so easy finally that i'm almost ashamed.
One question : Why your variable is a "var" instead a "user" ? I always see "var" instead of precise types. Is there any reason ?